# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to boot at startup, prompts fsck /dev/sda2

Tags: server, 20.04

Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed

after fsck
prompts "libmount.so:cannot open object  No such file or directory

How can I do?

Comment: Have you booted a *live* system and checked the health of you drive(s) (ie. using SMART) and then performed file-system checks on them (using appropriate commands for your *unstated* file-systems, as `fsck` can't check all file-system formats)

Comment: If your disk broke, you can only replace it and recover from your backup.